# Сложность с определением грамматических основ

Tags: грамматика, основа

"Но больше всего
удивляет в сказке не то, что в ней происходят чудеса, а то, что чудо может
произойти с любым, кто начинает читать, рассказывать или слушать сказку."

В ответах пишут, что тут 4 грамматические основы: *не то удивляет; чудеса происходят; чудо может произойти; кто начинает читать, рассказывать или слушать*. А может ли быть 5-й эта: *то* (т. е. двусоставное неполное предложение, можно подставить сказуемое "удивляет")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Здесь действительно 4 грамматические основы:**

1) удивляет  не то,  а то;

2) что  происходят чудеса;

3) что чудо может произойти;

4) кто начинает читать, рассказывать или слушать.

**Удивляет не то**, а **то** -  однородные подлежащие. Ваш вопрос говорит о том, что у Вас есть языковая интуиция. Дело в том, что некоторые учёные придерживаются мнения, что вопрос об однородности главных членов очень спорный, так как второй главный член легко восстанавливается и получается, что он тоже как бы существует (нулевая синтаксическая позиция, как нулевое окончание, нулевой суффикс, нулевая связка). **Однако в школе придерживаются другого мнения, школьные учебники признают и однородные подлежащие, и однородные сказуемые**. В вузе изучают **все** позиции, там бы пришлось объяснять: такой-то учёный считает, что..., а другой придерживается другого мнения, а я считаю... В школьных заданиях приходится считаться с мнением создателя учебника.

Comment: Людмила, объясните, пожалуйста, почему Вы отнесли "с любым" (местоим. сущ. с предлогом) к сказуемому?

Comment: Да нет, конечно, "с любым" - дополнение, скопировала часть текста и не убрала лишнее. Спасибо, сейчас уберу.

Comment: Ну вот — и моя дилетантность на что-то сгодилась.

Comment: Людмила, а союзы _что_ тоже, наверно, надо убрать?

Comment: Римма, не поняла про дилетантность - это Вы-то дилетант? Разве Вы не филолог?

Comment: Александр, конечно, союзы - это средства связи, к основе не относятся. Это я тогда торопилась, забежала на минутку, просто подсела уже на этот сайт, хоть и времени нет, а надо глянуть. Вижу, что ответа нет, не удержалась. А когда поспешишь...