# Грамматические основы

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, однородные-члены

> Только овсы да греча ждут еще своего часа, а пока что приманивают готовящиеся к дальним перелетам журавлиные стаи.

Это простое или сложное предложение? Здесь *приманивают* будет в составе однородных сказуемых или это двусоставное неполное предложение? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Покос закончен давным-давно, рожь убрана с полей, горохи тоже. Только **овсы** да **греча ждут** ещё своего часа, а пока что **приманивают** готовящиеся к дальним перелётам, усиленно кормящиеся перед дальней дорогой журавлиные стаи.* (В. Солоухин)

Предложение простое, в нём ***ждут*** и ***приманивают*** — однородные сказуемые. По поводу неполного предложения (пропущенного подлежащего в данном случае), однородности/неоднородности хорошо было сказано в ответе Людмилы на Ваш [предыдущий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460762/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).